# How to import and plot every file in folder using Python and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that reads a .csv file from specified folder and it generates .png with plotted chart. How can I write loop which would read all files from folder one by one and for each plot their chart (.png) respectively.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime



# csv header
time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
col_names = ["first_action_time","stable", "smooth", "sbase", "prebase", "leastsquares","uplift","base"]
dtypes = ["object", "uint8", "uint8", "uint8", "uint8", "uint8", "uint8", "uint8"]

# read from csv 
data = np.genfromtxt('D:\python34\\data_2016-10-09 08_26_28.csv',skip_header=1,usecols = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), names=col_names, delimiter=';',  dtype=dtypes)

# x-axis datetimeformat
x = [datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), time_format) for x in data['first_action_time']]

datemin=min(x)
datemax=max(x)

#plt.title(importame)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,8))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

plt.plot(x,data['stable'],color='purple',label='stable')
plt.plot(x,data['smooth'],color='green',label='smooth')
plt.plot(x,data['sbase'],color='orange',label='sbase')
#plt.plot(x,data['prebase'],color='yellow',label='prebase')
#plt.plot(x,data['leastsquares'],color='red',label='leastsquares')
plt.plot(x,data['uplift'],color='blue',label='uplift',linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x,np.array(data['base']),color='red',label='base',linestyle='dashed')
plt.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('D:\python34\\test.png')
```

Comment: How many files do you need to plot? 10,100,1000 or more?

Comment: At the moment I have 720 files, but I am asking in general. Sometimes I'd need to plot 10 files, and sometimes 10000...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general and most simple case would be to create the figures in a loop and save them. The only important thing to mind is that the previous figure should be closed before creating a new one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

#create list of files
files = glob.glob("*.csv")

#loop over list
for f in files:
    # read in data
    data = np.genfromtxt(f) 
    #close previous figure, if one exists
    plt.close()
    #create new figure and do plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.plot(data)
    #save figure
    plt.savefig(f[:-4]+".png")
```

See also

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368570/4124317
2. [Matplotlib and Pyplot.close() not releasing memory? - backend related Qt4Agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632694/matplotlib-and-pyplot-close-not-releasing-memory-backend-related-qt4agg)
3. [How to speed up matplotlib when plotting and saving lots of figures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688318/how-to-speed-up-matplotlib-when-plotting-and-saving-lots-of-figures)

for the case that plotting is too slow or consumes too much memory.