# bin one column and sum the other of (2,N) array

Tags: python, numpy

**Question:**

I have a dataset like the following:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.arange(0,10000,0.5)
y = np.arange(x.size)/x.size
```

Plotting in log-log space, it looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Obviously there is a lot of redundant information in this log log plot. 
I don't need 10000 points to represent this trend.

My question is this: how can I bin this data so that it displays a uniform number of points in each order of magnitude of the logarithmic scale? At each order of magnitude I'd like to get about ten points. Hence I need to bin 'x' with an exponentially growing bin size, and then take the average of all elements of `y` corresponding to each bin.

**Attempt:**

First I generate the bins I want to use for `x`.

```
# need a nicer way to do this.
# what if I want more than 10 bins per order of magnitude? 
bins = 10**np.arange(1,int(round(np.log10(x.max()))))
bins = np.unique((bins.reshape(-1,1)*np.arange(0,11)).flatten())

#array([    0,     10,    20,    30,    40,    50,    60,    70,    80,
#          90,   100,   200,   300,   400,   500,   600,   700,   800,
#         900,  1000,  2000,  3000,  4000,  5000,  6000,  7000,  8000,
#        9000, 10000])
```

Second, I find the index of the bin to which each element of x corresponds:

```
digits = np.digitize(x, bins)
```

Now the part I can really use help with. I want to take the average of every element in `y` corresponding to each bin, and then plot these averages versus the bin midpoints:

```
# need a nicer way to do this.. is there an np.searchsorted() solution?
# this way is quick and dirty, but it does not scale with acceptable speed
averages = []
for d in np.unique(digits):
    mask = digits==d
    y_mean = np.mean(y[mask])
    averages.append(y_mean)
del mask, y_mean, d    

# now plot the averages within each bin against the center of each bin 
plt.loglog((bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2.0, averages)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Summary:**
Is there a smoother way to do this? How can I generate an arbitrary `n` points per order of magnitude instead of 10?

Comment: Just curious about why splitting them into bins result in less resources consumed than actually plotting them?

Comment: Hi @Anoop-- it's because `len(averages)` is 28 in this example while `len(y)` is 10000, so the first plot has 10000 points in it while the second has less than 30. In my application the datasets actually have closer to 10 million points in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer two of your several questions: How to create bins alternatively and generate an arbitrary `n` points per order of magnitude instead of 10?

You can make use of [`np.logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) and [`np.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html#numpy.outer) to create your bins for any arbitrary `n` value as following. The default base in `logspace` is 10. It generates logarithmically spaced points similar to `linspace` which generates linearly spaced mesh.

*For `n=10`*

```
n = 10
bins = np.unique(np.outer(np.logspace(0, 3, 4), np.arange(0, n+1)))
# array([0.e+00, 1.e+00, 2.e+00, 3.e+00, 4.e+00, 5.e+00, 6.e+00, 7.e+00,
#        8.e+00, 9.e+00, 1.e+01, 2.e+01, 3.e+01, 4.e+01, 5.e+01, 6.e+01,
#        7.e+01, 8.e+01, 9.e+01, 1.e+02, 2.e+02, 3.e+02, 4.e+02, 5.e+02,
#        6.e+02, 7.e+02, 8.e+02, 9.e+02, 1.e+03, 2.e+03, 3.e+03, 4.e+03,
#        5.e+03, 6.e+03, 7.e+03, 8.e+03, 9.e+03, 1.e+04])
```

*For `n=20`*

```
n = 20
bins = np.unique(np.outer(np.logspace(0, 3, 4), np.arange(0, n+1)))
# array([0.0e+00, 1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 3.0e+00, 4.0e+00, 5.0e+00, 6.0e+00, 7.0e+00, 8.0e+00, 9.0e+00, 1.0e+01, 1.1e+01, 1.2e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.4e+01, 1.5e+01, 1.6e+01, 1.7e+01, 1.8e+01, 1.9e+01, 2.0e+01, 3.0e+01, 4.0e+01, 5.0e+01, 6.0e+01, 7.0e+01, 8.0e+01, 9.0e+01, 1.0e+02, 1.1e+02, 1.2e+02, 1.3e+02, 1.4e+02, 1.5e+02, 1.6e+02, 1.7e+02, 1.8e+02, 1.9e+02, 2.0e+02, 3.0e+02, 4.0e+02, 5.0e+02, 6.0e+02, 7.0e+02, 8.0e+02, 9.0e+02, 1.0e+03, 1.1e+03, 1.2e+03, 1.3e+03, 1.4e+03, 1.5e+03, 1.6e+03, 1.7e+03, 1.8e+03, 1.9e+03, 2.0e+03, 3.0e+03, 4.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 6.0e+03, 7.0e+03, 8.0e+03, 9.0e+03, 1.0e+04, 1.1e+04, 1.2e+04, 1.3e+04, 1.4e+04, 1.5e+04, 1.6e+04, 1.7e+04, 1.8e+04, 1.9e+04, 2.0e+04])
```

**EDIT**

If you want `0, 10, 20, 30...90, 100, 200, 300...` you can do the following

```
n = 10
bins = np.unique(np.outer(np.logspace(1, 3, 3), np.arange(0, n+1)))
# array([    0.,    10.,    20.,    30.,    40.,    50.,    60.,    70.,
#           80.,    90.,   100.,   200.,   300.,   400.,   500.,   600.,
#          700.,   800.,   900.,  1000.,  2000.,  3000.,  4000.,  5000.,
#         6000.,  7000.,  8000.,  9000., 10000.])
```

Comment: what if I want the smallest bin to be between `0` and `10`? I realize I can't bin my data within that range without destroying it. So the `n=10` sequence should be `0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, ...`

Comment: `bins = np.unique(np.outer(np.logspace(1, 3, 3), np.arange(0, n+2)))`?

Comment: @kevinkayaks: You were close. But you just have to use `n+1`. You used `(1,3,3)` correctly. Check my edit

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot. Now I'll work on the averaging all `y` corresponding to each bin component

Comment: @kevinkayaks: In your approach, you don't need to `flatten` because `np.unique` already give you a flattened 1-d array.